# Z-Index won't work when I try to place video as background on landing page

Tags: html, css, sass, frontend

I am a front-end noob and have started making myself a web portfolio to get better at coding. I took an open-source template from Traversy Media and have been making it my own. The problem is that I want my video editing reel to be the background of my landing page. I **cannot** get this to work no matter what I try. No matter what, it always sits in front of my logo and buttons. I even had my buddy, who is a front-end developer, take a look at it and he was stumped. Z-index's don't work, I made sure to add position: relative to everything and nope.

I am using sass which I am not really familiar with. My guess is that it's something in the sass that is overriding whatever I do to the video/logo. Either that or I messed up the structure of my html in some way. At this point I have no idea what the solution is, so here is my repo: https://github.com/rkgregory/modern_portfolio-master.

Here is my code

```css
@import "config";
@import "menu";

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  @include background;
  background: $primary-color;
  color: set-text-color($primary-color);
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

// Headings
h1,
h2,
h3 {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 400;

  &.lg-heading {
    font-size: 6rem;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  &.sm-heading {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    padding: 0.2rem 1rem;
    //background: rgba(lighten($primary-color, 2), 0.5);
  }
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

// trying to add video

header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

// .v-header {
//   height: 100vh;
//   display: flex;
//   align-items: center;
// }

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.fullscreen-video-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fullscreen-video-wrap video {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

// done trying to add video

.ondary {
  color: $secondary-color;
}

main {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4rem;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 60 px);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 200;

  .rg-logo {
    width: 60%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 300;
  }

  .custom-container {
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 30vh;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 300;
  }

  .icons {
    margin-top: 1rem;

    a {
      padding: 0.4rem;
      @include easeOut;
      color: black;

      &:hover {
        color: #fff;
      }
    }
  }

  &#home {
    overflow: hidden;

    h1 {
      margin-top: 20vh;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<body id="bg-img">
  <header>
    <div class="fullscreen-video-wrap">
      <video src="./img/code.mov" autoplay="true" loop="true"></video>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-btn">
      <div class="btn-line"></div>
      <div class="btn-line"></div>
      <div class="btn-line"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <nav class="menu">
        <div class="menu-branding">
          <div class="portrait"></div>
        </div>
        <ul class="menu-nav">
          <li class="nav-item current">
            <a href="index.html" class="nav-link">
              Home
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="about.html" class="nav-link">
              About Me
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="work.html" class="nav-link">
              My Work
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="contact.html" class="nav-link">
              How To Reach Me
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
  </header>

  <main id="home">
    <div class="custom-container">
      <img class="rg-logo" src="./img/rg-logo.svg" alt="">
      <!-- <h2 class="sm-heading">
        Writer, Video Editor, and Web Developer
      </h2> -->
      <div class="icons">
        <a href="#!">
          <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="#!">
          <i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-2x"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>

  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Please let me know if I am missing relevant information. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't add `z-index:-1` to video container but directly to `<video>`.

Change:

```
.fullscreen-video-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
 }
 .fullscreen-video-wrap video {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;

    z-index: 2;
 }
```

to:

```
.fullscreen-video-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    z-index: -1;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
 }
 .fullscreen-video-wrap video {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: I gave that a shot and it didn't work. I have essentially added z-index's to everything I could with no solutions

Comment: Add `z-index:-1` to video wrap